# sqlite trigger updateof multiple columns

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I want to make a trigger to be executed when any of a list of columns are updated. By:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trTeams] AFTER UPDATE OF [pTeam0], [pTeam1], ... [pTeam9]
ON [games] FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE games SET tTime = time('now', 'localtime') WHERE new.id = id;
END
```

the trigger does not work. (Maybe it does work if ALL pTeamX are updated?)

How can I create a trigger to work in an update of any of the columns?
Thank you.
P.S. It DOES WORK at datetime() instead of time() although tTime column is typeof TIME.

Comment: This looks correct. What exactly do you mean with "does not work"?

Comment: I mean that by changing a value of e.g. pTeam0 via sqlite administrator, the tTime remains unchanged. Although I use datetime (see P.S.) and it's ok now. Thank you for your time.